# Remove all Input fields by Name with Index

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove all input fields with a name value beginning with "List" plus a variable. I have tried it like below but no joy so far.

```
$('input[name^=List[' + index + '].LastName]').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `name` attribute includes special characters (the `[]`) you need to either escape them in the selector:

```
$('input[name^=List\\[' + index + '\\].LastName]').remove();
```

Or better yet, place the attribute value in quotes:

```
$('input[name^="List[' + index + '].LastName"]').remove();
```